# Quirky Directories

Tags: c#, .net

I've got an issue with some directory manipulation.

The problem is I have an archive of data that needs to be add or purge backup data based on a series of constraints.  The constraint that is an issue is the archive only needs to keep the backup from the previous week.

So when you chart out the steps you would assume:

- Check if directory exist.
- Grab the files.
- Then purge them.
- Then move the following week into the directory.

The problem though is when you try keep the code simple and implementation, you create some code that doesn't feel like it is proper practice.

```
string[] archiveFiles = Directory.GetFiles(
     Archive, @"*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

foreach(string archive in archiveFiles)
     File.Delete(archive);
```

So if you attempt to grab the files with `Directory.GetFiles()` and it doesn't return a value, according to the documentation:

> Return Value Type: System.String[] An array of the full names
>   (including paths) for the files in the specified directory that match
>   the specified search pattern and option, or an empty array if no files
>   are found.

If it returns a `null` in the array then that would actually have the loop iterate once, an error.  If it returns an array with no elements then it will ignore the loop.  The second is what I believe it does, which makes this approach feel incorrect.

The only thing I could do would be to use `File.Copy()` as it can overwrite files, which would avoid this approach but even that could become suceiptable to the same dilemma of that empty array.

Is that right usage and approach for `Directory.GetFiles()` or is there a better way?

Comment: About `GetFiles` you are right. But apparently next loop once executed then you won't have any file in the top level directory.

Comment: This isn't very clear.  Why would *not* deleting files that already don't exist be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> If it returns a null in the array then that would actually have the
>   loop iterate once, an error. If it returns an array with no elements
>   then it will ignore the loop. The second is what I believe it does,
>   which makes this approach feel incorrect.

If there are no files matching the list will be empty, there won't be nulls (how many nulls should return an empty directory?).

So your delete code will not be executed. Makes sense to me.

If you need to delete old files, then copy the new ones you may want to first move old files somewhere safe, then copy new ones, then to delete old files.

Maybe I didnt understand the problem here, but I don't see any. I hope actual code has some try catches though.